# out of memory of android application,when BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream()

Tags: android, memory

all, I meet a out of memory  exception on my phone(4.4.4 MotoX). After take photo, I read it from sdcard-path, then the exception occurs.

```
12-18 11:12:47.294  11966-11966/com.geexfinance.geexfinance E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 42024976-byte allocation.
12-18 10:15:42.099  12905-12905/com.geexfinance.geexfinance E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.geexfinance.geexfinance, PID: 12905
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:620)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:634)
            at com.geexfinance.geexfinance.model.GeexCache.getBitmap(GeexCache.java:1825)
            at com.geexfinance.geexfinance.model.GeexCache.getBitmap(GeexCache.java:1940)
            at com.geexfinance.geexfinance.ui.GeexApplyInstallmentFragment.onActivityResult(GeexApplyInstallmentFragment.java:532)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5450)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3428)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It looks strange, I run the same application on a Huawei-pad(4.4.3), OOM never occurs.

I watch the memory-monitor of ANDROID_STUDIO. On my phone , memory allocated from 32MB to 90MB,and OOM exception always occurs when it is about 48MB.on my pad, memory allocated from 32MB to 40MB, never meet a OOM.

I have some questions:

- my phone have 2048MB memory ,why only a 42MB allocation leads a OOM?
- why OOM occurs when memory is 48MB,it's not a the memory peak.
- same application, same user behavior(take 3 photos), why phone have a exception and pad not?

Comment: @Elltz when testing,I close all other applications I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my phone have 2048MB memory ,why only a 42MB allocation leads a OOM?
```

Total RAM memory of the device is not related to heap size allocated per application instance.

```
why OOM occurs when memory is 48MB,it's not a the memory peak.
```

OOM occurs when the requested memory is over the heap size, as mentioned above.

```
same application, same user behavior(take 3 photos), why phone have a exception and pad not?
```

There are many factors associated with NOT being able to reproduce the OOM, could be the photo details and size, could be the current memory consumption of the app at that point of time. Do some reading on how to process large `Bitmap`s efficiently, I'm sure the issue will go away.

Answer (score 0):

may be it needs **large heap**, try to write in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```